# ReSharper VS CodeRush performance

Tags: performance, resharper, coderush

I have seen extensive articles and blogs posts on the comparison, but what about the performance?

I am fine with the function of ReSharper but the performance is unbearable.

I am willing to change to escape that pitfall, but will I actually be escaping it?

I'm not asking anyone to do statistics on a fresh machine, but what is the approximate factor? I'm looking for something more than just "blank is faster".

2 / 1?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Firstly, full disclosure: I have just finished running through the full trial period for both Resharper and Coderush, and in the end I spent my money on Resharper.

To directly answer your question - yes, in my experience Coderush is much faster than Resharper. Often with Resharper the entire UI will pause for a fraction of second or so while it performs the dynamic compile to test for errors in the code, and you can visibly see the sidebar refresh. Coderush on the hand added very little noticeable performance penalty.

I stuck with Resharper though for two reasons: Firstly the feature set it provides is simply a better fit for my work style. I gave Coderush four weeks to win me other, but its main selling point (the frankly brilliant templating engine) never made up for the lack of functionality that I had learnt to rely on in my four weeks with Resharper. Secondly I noticed that the performance of Resharper dramatically improved with the latest version the slowdown was only really bad on files that were in need of refactoring anyway - files created with Resharper in mind tended to work very well as there were less errors being flagged.

Both tools have generous trial period though and I had no problem installing, uninstalling and flip-flopping between the two of them, so the best thing I can suggest is to try for yourself. For me Coderush is faster and feels more professional, but Resharper has functionality I wasn't willing to give up.

Comment: FWIW Coderush 9.2 (available currently only as a trial. Contact me on twitter @RoryBecker if you'd like a link) is insanely fast and memory efficient compared to any previous version.

Comment: CodeRush 9.2 performance is detailed here -> http://community.devexpress.com/blogs/markmiller/archive/2009/06/17/performance-and-memory-milestones-in-coderush-and-refactor-pro-preview-of-9-2.aspx.

Comment: Can you please name those features of Resharper? I tried to compare trial versions but didn't find anything that R# does better than CR.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the feedback. Can you go into more detail on which features you found one had over the other? what were you not willing to give up?

For me, the only feature I like in ReSharper that CodeRush is lacking is Unit Testing. Everything else, I find CodeRush to exceed in...but I'm new to both products, so I would like to know more.

Comment: Off the top of my head there is the unit testing, better support for interfaces (Resharper has useful features to move to and from the implementations of an interface methods. Since pretty much everything in my current project is accessed through interfaces this is a God send), and better (though not perfect) XMAL support. In the end CodeRush made it faster to write the code and Resharper made it faster to navigate and refactor it, and I do far more of the later.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Martin, but also would say that since version 4.5 ReSharper is alot faster especially on large projects.

I went with coderush for sometime but having worked with in a dev team I would say R# is still the most useful.

I have some discount coupons and extended trials for ReSharper if you are interested:

http://web2asp.net/2009/09/resharper-discount-and-extended-trial.html